# format a table with a nested column with kable()

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyr, kable, kableextra

I am making an R markdown doc showing the process of making some simulations. In short, the simulations will be combinations of two variables, each with 100 trials. Sometimes, I want to show a dataframe in the .rmd as the simulation dataframe is being built. Sometimes, this means showing a dataframe with a nested column (nested with `tidyr`) just to show "look, there are 100 things here".

When I use `head()` to show a dataframe with a nested column, the nested column shows as `<list>` with the dimensions (see pic 1). see pic below. I like this output because all I want to show is "look, there are 100 things collapsed in here".

[image: pic 1 - output from head()]

However, when I use `kable()`, (which I would prefer for formatting reasons,) it expands the list column with commas, which I don't love. see here:

[image]

Is there a way I can have the kable formatting, but still have the nested column show as `<tibble [100 × 1]>`?

R chunk for rmd here:

````
    \```{r , message=FALSE} <- remove slash
    
    library(tibble)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(knitr)
    library(kableExtra)
    
    
    df <- tibble(
      var1 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
      var2 = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
    ) %>%
      group_by(var1, var2) %>%
      slice(rep(1:n(), each = 100)) %>%
      mutate(trial = c(1:n())) %>%
      nest(data = trial)
    
    head(df)
    
    kable(head(df)) %>%
        kable_minimal() 
    \``` <- remove that slash
````

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, use `reactable`

````
\```{r , message=FALSE, echo = FALSE} 

library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(knitr)
library(reactable)

df <- tibble(
  var1 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  var2 = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
) %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 100)) %>%
  mutate(trial = c(1:n())) %>%
  nest(data = trial)


reactable(df %>% 
              ungroup %>%
               mutate(data = NULL), details = function(index) {
  tmp <- df$data[[index]]
  htmltools::div(style = "padding: 16px", reactable(tmp))

})
\```
````

-output

[image]